# Does PHP have a built-in alternative to exec("nslookup")?

Tags: php, shell

I have the following command in my PHP class:

```
@exec('nslookup -type=' . $type . ' ' . escapeshellcmd($host), $output);
```

This doesn't run on my server because of security restrictions (`exec` and `escapeshellcmd` are disabled from php.ini). Is there any alternative that doesn't rely on `exec`?

Comment: Side note: For a single argument, you should use `escapeshellarg` rather then `escapeshellcmd`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `dns_get_record()`:

http://www.php.net/dns_get_record

Comment: *in PHP 5.3 and above (that is, it works on Windows since 5.3 -- Linux platforms have had it since 5.0)

Comment: @Justin Not true. It exists in Windows since 5.3

Answer (score 1):

I use the built-in `gethostbyname($hostname)` for that: pass it a domain name and it returns the ip if it can be found or the unmodified input string otherwise. `gethostbyaddr($ip)` goes the other way round.

See also:
- [gethostbyname](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php) documentation
- [gethostbyaddr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyaddr.php) documentation

Answer (score 1):

The PHP `dns_get_record()` function is a simple way of doing it. However, be aware that if the user changes their hosts file, `dns_get_record()` will then return the value set in the hosts file and not query an authoritative DNS server.